# Error white listing domain for messenger bot using php

Tags: php, messenger

i get this error while trying to white list my app domain using php on the messenger platform

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter setting_type is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"H4+VMmlq3Ab"}}

here is the json

```
$domain_white = '{
"whitelisted_domains":[
"https://aadb-3120.herokuapp.com"
]
}';
```

`

and my  curl

```
    function curl($input)
    {
        global $accessToken;
        global $input;
       $ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$accessToken);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $input);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      error_log($output); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `setting_type`, which is required:

```
{
  "setting_type": "domain_whitelisting",
  "whitelisted_domains": [
    "https://aadb-3120.herokuapp.com"
  ],
  "domain_action_type": "add"
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589797/error-getting-user-id-from-messenger-webview-even-after-white-listing-domain could you help me with this too @PedroLobito