# Error getting user id from messenger webview even after white listing domain

Tags: php, messenger

i have white listed my domain and i get a message showing it was successful

> {"result": "Successfuly updated whitelisted domains"}

but when i try getting the user id I get the error message

> An error occuredMessenger Extensions are not enabled - could be "messenger_extensions" was not set on a url, the domain was not whitelisted or this is an outdated version of Messenger client

i am using A PC so an outdated version might not be it, and i have the messenger extension set this way

```
$get_started_display = "{
'recipient':{
'id': $sender_id
},
'message':{
'attachment':{
  'type':'template',
  'payload':{
    'template_type':'button',
    'text':'Click a button below to continue',
    'buttons':[

      {
        'type':'web_url',
        'title':'Add Leader Profile',
        'url':'https://aadb-3120.herokuapp.com/login.html',
        'webview_height_ratio' : 'full',
        'messenger_extensions': true
      },
      {
        'type':'postback',
        'title':'Review Added Profile',
        'payload':'review'
      },

      {
        'type':'postback',
        'title':'Help',
        'payload':'help'
       },
     ]
   }
  }
 }
}";
please what are my doing wrong?
```

Comment: You may want to read: https://community.flowxo.com/t/whitelisting-domains-for-facebook-send-api/917

Comment: Thanks for the link@PedroLobito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the Admins at the messenger platform community just confirmed that webviews extension don't work on PC, so the only way i can get the User ID is by adding it to the URL on the URL button or through session variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is a valid json format. It should be in double quotes not single quotes. Why don't you write in php array instead and convert to json to reduce your chances of making mistakes.

eg.

```
$data = [
'recipient' => [
    'id' => $sender_id
],
'message' => [
    'attachment' => [
        'type' => 'template',
        'payload' => [
            'template_type' => 'button',
            'text' => 'Click a button below to continue',
            'buttons' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'web_url',
                    'url' => 'https://google.com',
                    'title' => 'Visit Google',
                    "webview_height_ratio" => "compact"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]];


$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, this works too, one of admins @the messenger platform community just confirmed to me that messenger webviews don't work on PC's so i have to add the user_id to the URL, or store it in session variables.